# Горизонтальный скрол широкой картинки

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, swift

Создаю level map для игры. Есть картинка с высотой девайса, а шириной давольно таки большой.
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

И UIScrollView, и UIImageView добавил в через сториборд
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

При запуске карта отображается не с начала левого края картинки и скролится тоже не до самого правого края картинки. 
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Как задать размеры элементам, чтобы скролилась целиком карта?
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Нужно больше подробностей, как Вы что расставили.

Comment: Констрейнты вот в таком виде, добавил нижний скрин в вопрос

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Нужно установить Layout'ы для `UIImageView` `width` и `height` как константы. Добавить `Top Left = 0`.
Сейчас размер `UIImgView` привязан к размеру `ScrollView`.